# why passing arguments backward in IA32 stack procedure?

Tags: c, x86, stack

If I have a function foo(arg1, arg2). In IA32 stack, arg2 is first pushed then arg1 is pushed, so that the callee function access the arg1 by %ebp+8 and access arg2 by %ebp+12, but what is the reason to push backwards? (Our processor mentioned something about printf and count, but I don't really understand). Also in general, the caller function never passes count of the arguments (how many arguments are there), how can callee function know then?
Many thanks!

Comment: That's just the C calling convention.  C supports functions with a variable number of arguments, main() and printf() are common examples.  By passing them "backwards", the 1st argument is always in a known location.

Comment: The callee will "know" how many arguments there are because the *compiler* knows at compile-time and sees to reserve the appropriate amount of stack space and generate code to access the values. Any number of var-args is implicitly converted to a single *array* (plus the array's length) and passed as a reference to the callee.

Comment: And in C convention, the variable number of arguments is always the first one? This would make sense. However, if you push them in normal order, you would also know "the number of arguments" is always the last one, right?

Comment: I can see it is easier but it is not necessary, is it?

Answer (score 1):

In assembly level, it doesn't matter if you pass parameters on stack in written or reverse order, but chosen method must be same as one used by called function. C usually pushes values in reverse order, because it needs to suppor `varargs` - variable number of parameters. If the parameters were pushed in order as written, it wouldn't be easy to get the first one.

Modern languages like Java or C# (and .NET generally) can push values normally, as they handle additional parameters as arrays (so there's only one parameter passed to called function - pointer to array).

C example:

```
.data
format: db "Your lucky number is %d", 0
....

;code is equivalent to printf("Your lucky number is %d", 10);
push dword 10
push format
call printf
```

Java example:

```
 0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 3: ldc           #3                  // String Your lucky number is %d
 5: iconst_1
 6: anewarray     #4                  // class java/lang/Object
 9: dup
10: iconst_0
11: bipush        10
13: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf(I)Ljavava/lang/Integer;
16: aastore
17: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.printf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/io/PrintStream;
20: pop
```

Comment: Where does "push 10" come from?

Comment: It is the number to be printed.